# Archive Pages Only Showing 1 Post from Caregory

Tags: archives

Suddenly my wordpress site is showing only 1 post in archive pages. I am not being able to figure out whats wrong in archive.php or archive-loop.php. I use a customer theme which I made years ago, but it was working just fine. I have checked the settings where it has 15 posts set to be displayed. Any pointers?

khujbo.com

Comment: What’s the code?

Comment: is the page you are referring to created by custom code or a block?